# one class SVM modelling

Tags: svm

I have some doubts about how to model a system based on one class SVM, which I plan to use for detecting outliers or anomalous data. For example, when I used a neural network or SVM model the procedure I followed was roughly the following:

1. Normalize if needed both train and test data
2. Shuffle the data
3. Divide the data into train and test data with their respective labels
4. Apply model

I have not used one class SVM before and I want to measure some rare events. So I have a dataset that contains the normal behaviour of an event, lets called data1. Also, I have a small dataset that also belongs to data 1, approximately 20% of the size of data1, but it contains rare events or what could be considered as outliers and lets called data2. I have followed these steps for the one svm model:

1. Normalize both datasets
2. Divide the data into train and test set, here I do not have labels
3. Train the model with the train data or data 1 and test it with data 2

I was wondering if there is the need to shuffle the data as it was done in the supervised models or can I train and test them without doing that step. It might sound rather a simple question, but I was not able to find any information about how to do it, and in some examples on the web they do not perform this step.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to **shuffle** data for **SVM**, as it's **nonparametric** learning algorithm, moreover most **built-in** implementation uses the Sequential minimal optimization (**SMO**) algorithm, the algorithm uses a **heuristic** for choosing which example **eligible** for optimization.

---

It's not a part of your question, but I would like to mention that **normalization** going to **hurt** your objective (**outliers detection**), as there's some **trade off** between **normalization** and **outliers**, roughly speaking by normalizing input-space you are going to reduce the outliers (influence), and for SVM it's meant that, the distance (i.e. **support vectors linear response**) going to be reduced too.